# Fastest login check for large database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to start a big project where `users` table will have a lots of rows.

> ```
> Users table structure is this: id|username|password|email
>
> id - auto_increment + primary_key
> username - unique index
> email - unique index
> ```

I want for my users to be able login with username or email, but if this will slow my query i'll use only one input.

I. (Both Username or Email login)
My execute stmt for this:

```
$post_input = $_POST['user_input'] //will be username or email

$check = $db->prepare("Select * from users where username=? or email=?")
$check->execute(array($post_input,$post_input));
if($check->rowCount() > 0){
   //Username or Email found from here do the rest of the things
}
```

II . (Only Username login)
My execute stmt for this:

```
$post_input = $_POST['user_input'] //will be username

$check = $db->prepare("Select * from users where username=?")
$check->execute(array($post_input));
if($check->rowCount() > 0){
   //Username found from here do the rest of the things
}
```

Which one of this queries will perform better and faster when users table will reach like 1 million users.

Comment: Obiviously the second one will because it checks for only username...

Comment: If you add an index to both columns, you can search using both.

Comment: The difference shouldn't matter that much anyway; I'd rather be able to log in with either and wait an extra second or two (probably not even that much).

Comment: Yet another question on wannabe-big project.

Comment: Is that really what you're trying to ask? The second one will *obviously* be faster. That is obvious, isn't it??

Comment: @BillyMathews i'm asking coz i never deal with big databases. so i tough if both username and email is indexed will not matter.

YourCommonSense: If will not be a big project i wouldn't ask this questions. Thanks for support

Comment: You're putting the cart way before the horse. Even with millions of users, the time necessary to search two columns should be insignificant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have your application check for an @ in the user input and if present check against email, if not check against username (could cause issues if @ is acceptable in username of course)

Answer (score 1):

Put `limit 0,1` at the end of your sql query, so it will stop searching when it gets one user from the database:

```
Select * from users where username=? limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

As andrewsi says: If you add an index to both columns, you can search using both. There will be no noticeable difference if you check both columns, even with with millions of rows.